# I can't put 2 IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't put 2 IMPORTRANGE in the Google Sheets QUERY. The spreadsheet only displays the results from the first spreadsheet that is in the QUERY, but does not show anything from the second.

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("19AAxbyONRxBPDphVNBA9fCNiK0l22EvlCDNDV8tYTQo";"VENDA!A2:H");IMPORTRANGE("1gxll5dzZNjBv5IJeIskWK2iREqwx_YGXvnrvKYRXS6I";"VENDA!A2:H")})

I wanted a spreadsheet that combined data from 2 spreadsheets into one.

Comment: any chance second importrange is loaded as well but its way below at row 1001 or 2001  in the combined page since 1st 1000 rows for example are accommodated for first importrange data ( which has both data rows + empty rows per se.,)

Comment: agree with prev. comment.  Scroll down to the bottom and you'll find the data.  Add a condition to the query(), "where Col1 is not null"